# java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; while using JPA 2.2 query.getResultStream().findFirst()

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x, jpa-2.2

The code of my Spring Data repository method is as follows:

```
public Optional<byte[]> findShipmentLabelByClientIdAndAwb(String clientId, String awb) {

    String queryString = "select g.shipmentLabel as shipmentLabel from GenericShipment g where g.client.id = :clientId and g.shipmentId = :awb " +
        " AND (g.processingStatus is null or g.processingStatus <> 'DELETED') AND g.shipmentLabel is not null";

    val query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, byte[].class);

    query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
    query.setParameter("awb", awb);

    return query.getResultStream().findFirst();

}
```

As you can see, I am attempting to fetch, as byte array, the **shipmentLabel** column, defined in my Postgres schema as **bytea**.
The following exception occurs at runtime:

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object**;
> at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.prepareCurrentRow(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:203)
> at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:101)
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.ScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(ScrollableResultsIterator.java:33)
> at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1811)
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
> at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
> at **org.hibernate.query.spi.StreamDecorator.findFirst(StreamDecorator.java:260)**

I was wondering if this is the intended behaviour here or not, thanks in advance for your answers.

For the time being, the workaround is to use the JPA 2.1 variant:

> return query.getResultList().stream().findFirst();

As environment, I am using **Spring Boot 2.3.3**, **Hibernate** version is **5.4.20**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `getResultList` first, and see if it works:

```
public Optional<Byte[]> findShipmentLabelByClientIdAndAwb(
        String clientId, String awb) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("""
        select 
            g.shipmentLabel as shipmentLabel 
        from GenericShipment g 
        where 
            g.client.id = :clientId and 
            g.shipmentId = :awb and 
            (
                g.processingStatus is null or 
                g.processingStatus <> 'DELETED'
            ) and 
            g.shipmentLabel is not null
        """)
    .setParameter("clientId", clientId)
    .setParameter("awb", awb)
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .getResultList()
    .stream()
    .findFirst();
}
```

Note that it's inefficient to select N records only to take the first one using `fidFirst`. What if this query returns 100 records? You'd still select all 100 from the DB.

That's why I added the `setMaxResults` call.

If that doesn't work, try debugging the Hibernate `BinaryType` and see why it doesn't return `byte[]`.

Comment: With our current data model and constraints, it is quite impossible to have more than one record returned for the given WHERE clause. I will try to use Byte[] instead of the primitive and return with my findings, thanks.

Comment: query.getResultStream().findFirst() still fails in org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl at line 230, where it explicitly attempts to cast the primitive byte array to Object[]. Guess I will stick with query.getResultList().stream().findFirst().

Comment: Use `getResultLust().stream()` then and open a Hibernate Jira issue.

Comment: Thank you, I opened issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14231

Comment: This pull request should solve this in future releases: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3563

Comment: @DragoşHaiduc Cool. I'm glad Nathan was quick on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive stream for byte, you can check in the debugger what type of stream your are getting maybe `Stream<Byte[]>` or `Stream<Object[]>`. This can explain the exception you are getting. Using Byte[] should solve your issue.

```
public Optional<Byte[]> findShipmentLabelByClientIdAndAwb(String clientId, String awb) {
    String queryString = "select g.shipmentLabel as shipmentLabel from GenericShipment g where g.client.id = :clientId and g.shipmentId = :awb " +
        " AND (g.processingStatus is null or g.processingStatus <> 'DELETED') AND g.shipmentLabel is not null";

     val query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, Byte[].class);

     query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
     query.setParameter("awb", awb);

     return query.getResultStream().findFirst();
```

}

Comment: Tried this already, the following exception occurs: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [[Ljava.lang.Byte;] is incompatible with query return type [class [B]